# Calculate the frequency of species occurrence across sites

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I need to calculate a relative frequency of the species occurence across sites. Lets say, if the species `a` was found in 5 out of the 8 sampling sites, its relative frequency is 62.5 %. I wonder how to do it in R, ideally using `dplyr`?

Dummy example:

```
d <-data.frame(site = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4),
               species = c('a','b', 'a','b', 'a','d', 'a', 'e'))
```

I know that I can calculate the sum of unique sites by counting distinct ones:

```
d %>% 
  group_by(site) %>% 
  summarize(n_sites = n_distinct(site))
```

I can get the frequency of the individual species occurences using this:

```
d %>% 
  count(species)
```

But how can I get that the frequency of occurence of each species?

Desired output:

```
species freq
a       100  # species a is present in each plot
b        50  # b occurs in half of plots
d        25  # d&e occur only in 1 out of 4 plots
e        25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would break this into two steps, as follows:

```
d%>%
  group_by(species)%>%
  # Step 1; count sites by specices
  summarise(sites_by_species=n_distinct(site))%>%
  # Step 2; divide by total number of sites
  mutate(frequency=100*sites_by_species/n_distinct(d$site))
```

Output of which is:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  species sites_by_species frequency
  <chr>              <int>     <dbl>
1 a                      4       100
2 b                      2        50
3 d                      1        25
4 e                      1        25
```

Answer (score 2):

- We can use

```
library(dplyr)

d |> group_by(species) |> mutate(n = n_distinct(site)) |>
     summarise(freq = n()) |> ungroup() |> 
     mutate(freq = freq/n_distinct(species)*100)
```

- Output

```
 A tibble: 4 × 2
  species  freq
  <chr>   <dbl>
1 a         100
2 b          50
3 d          25
4 e          25
```

Answer (score 1):

Since we already `group_by` species, I guess we cannot use `n_distinct()` to find out the distinct sites, therefore I used `length(unique(d$site))`.

```
library(dplyr)

d %>% group_by(species) %>% summarize(freq = n()*100/length(unique(d$site)))
```

Or more lengthy (trying to stay in `dplyr` as much as possible):

```
d %>%  
  mutate(sites_n = n_distinct(site)) %>% 
  group_by(species) %>% 
  summarize(freq = n()*100/max(sites_n))
```

### Output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  species  freq
  <chr>   <dbl>
1 a         100
2 b          50
3 d          25
4 e          25
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d %>% 
  count(species) %>%
  mutate(freq=n/n_distinct(d$site)*100) %>%
  select(-n)


  species freq
1       a  100
2       b   50
3       d   25
4       e   25
```

I needed to use `d$site` since `site` is no longer available trough pipes after the use of `count`.